# How do you SELECT attributes of a custom type via a table alias?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to select the individual attributes of a custom typed column in PostgreSQL via a table alias? Without using a table alias, wrapping the name of the column in parens works fine. As soon as a table alias is introduced my query fails with a syntax error.

I've scoured the Postgres docs and haven't been able to find anything illustrating how to accomplish this. Surely this is possible?

```
CREATE TYPE test_type AS (
    some_text TEXT,
    some_number INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    some_test test_type NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_table (some_test)
VALUES (ROW('SOME TEXT', 42));

-- This works great

SELECT id, (some_test).some_text, (some_test).some_number
FROM test_table;
```

```
┌────┬───────────┬─────────────┐
│ id │ some_text │ some_number │
├────┼───────────┼─────────────┤
│  1 │ SOME TEXT │          42 │
└────┴───────────┴─────────────┘
```

As soon as the table alias is introduced you can't SELECT the 
individual attributes from the custom typed column

```
SELECT id, x.(some_test).some_text, x.(some_test).some_number
FROM test_table AS x;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: select id, x.(some_test).some_text, x.(some_test).some_numbe...
                     ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the parentheses around the combination of alias and column:

```
SELECT id, (x.some_test).some_text, (x.some_test).some_number
FROM test_table x;
```